# man pages convention: (square)bracket annotation in C function prototypes

Tags: c, manpage, function-prototypes

The `[.len]` annotation to the first argument — is that documented somewhere?
I could not find it here: `https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/man-pages.7.html`

I guess it is supposed to add clarity to the prototype but I've not seen this usage documented.

```
# examples
int pkey_mprotect(void addr[.len], size_t len, int prot, int pkey);
ssize_t read(int fd, void buf[.count], size_t count);
```

Comment: https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-man/msg22682.html

Comment: https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-man/msg23160.html